# Get a list items and send email notification to the user they are assigned

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a designer workflow using HTTP Web Service Call to query a list of items that are due for review and send an email to a group of users. But sometimes a few of the users that received the email does not have a work-items that are due for review (Resolved) which make the email irrelevant to them.

ON the I have a choice column named “Overall Status” with status: New, InProgress, and Resolved.
And another people picker column ‘Engineer”

**Web Service Call URL:**

```
https://sharepointSITE/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('SharePoint List')/Items?$expand= Engineer &$select=Title,Overall_x0020_Status,Engineer/UserName
```

Is there a way to filter the Web Service Call results and send each user an email with only the items that are assigned to them?

Comment: Have you tried add $filter=Engineer eq <UserId>?

Comment: I can but I don't know what the UserID would be. when querying the list, I can all items that are assigned to an engineer with there Overall status = resolved. from there I'm trying to sort them out and send an email to each engineer an email with only items that are assigned to them.

Comment: I can do it on a list workflow using the IF statement but that would require sending them multiple emails. using site workflow would be the best option if i can sort the results and send them a list of items assigned to them on one email.